# Accessing part of data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm very new to R and trying to understand data frames.  I have a question which I expect is very basic.  I've been looking at sample code on how to access a data frame, e.g.

```
women[1:3,]
women[women$height>100,]
```

And I don't understand what the comma in the above code means or what it does?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: means  women[rows, columns]  for data frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very brief introdution. For example, a [3 x 5] data frame, df.

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:15, 3, 5))
df[1:2, 4:5] # extract data from rows 1 to 2, columns 4 to 5
df[c(1, 3), 5] # extract data rows 1 and 3, column 5
df[, 5] # extract column 5 only
df[2, ] # extract row 2 only
df[df$V1 > 1, ] # extract element of V1 > 1
```

Comment: That explains it brilliantly.  Thanks!! :)